# Why are the first 2 characters of my tag altered?

Tags: transaction, javascript

I used the official javascript library to create and attach a transaction to the tangle, but the first 2 characters of the tag are always changed to some random characters.

eg. `HELLOWORLD9999999999999999` is changed to `XYLLOWORLD9999999999999999`

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Due to a bug in the signing process, the js lib needs to work around by altering the tag

Ref: 
[Why is the normalized hash considered insecure when containing the char 'M'](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/1241/why-is-the-normalized-hash-considered-insecure-when-containing-the-char-m)